# Is it okay if a submission has an extremely small chance of not functioning properly?

Tags: discussion

For instance, consider the following un-golfed submission in [c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) to some [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge requiring the use of a while looping construct:

```
void function() {
     int a, b;
     while(a != b) {
         // Do something
     }
}
```

Although the `while` loop would be invoked most of the time, there is an *extremely* small chance, but still a chance, that the un-initialized local variables `a` and `b` could start out with the same value. Is this okay? It would be nice to come to a consensus on this.

Comment: Well, you know, [cosmic rays could also just flip your RAM too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2580933/7605753) ([relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/378/))

Comment: similar question: [here](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline/blob/a703d4222e7638769cda9c459700e876673eb39f/compiler/interpreter/execute.pde#L1384) there is a well defined chance that it wont function properly (but it's way less than ~1E-303). Does anything differ in this case?

Comment: Every sane operating system will 0-initialize all memory pages before allocating them for userspace program (because of security reasons). So it's highly unlikely that the while loop is entered

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## No

If a program does not do what it is supposed to do, it is not valid as an answer. Otherwise we'd have to quantify what probability the answers have to work with, which is getting messy.

Comment: In that case, should this be added to our catalog of [forbidden loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)?

Comment: I don't think so, it is just an invalid answer in the first place.

Comment: @R.Kap, it's just a special case of [Adding input or rules which weren't explicitly mentioned in the challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1789/194).